# Why is trigger not fired on every single row when using "insert select" or "merge"

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb, triggers

I defined a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger for a table and it works as expected for single `INSERT`statements, but not for `INSERT ... SELECT` nor `MERGE` statements.

These are my database objects (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE "COMPANY" (
    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL,
    "NAME" VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEE" (
    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL,
    "COMPANY_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "EMPLOYEE_PK" ON "EMPLOYEE" ("ID");

CREATE SEQUENCE "EMPLOYEE_SEQUENCE";

CREATE TRIGGER "BI_EMPLOYEE" BEFORE INSERT ON "EMPLOYEE" 
    REFERENCING NEW AS newrow FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ATOMIC 
    IF newrow.id IS NULL THEN 
        SET newrow.id = NEXT VALUE FOR employee_sequence;
    END IF;
END;
```

If single `INSERT`statements are executed, everything works as expected, the `ÌD` is fetched from the sequence. But if I execute something like

```
INSERT INTO employee (company_id) SELECT id FROM company;
```

the I get an error:

```
integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation: "EMPLOYEE_PK"
```

which could propably mean that it tries to insert the same key from the sequence twice.

I'm using the latests version 2.3.2 of HSQLDB.

Comment: Are you aware that you can define your `employee.id` column as `generated by default as identity` which would remove the need for the trigger completely.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but unfortunately I have to reflect the structure of an oracle database (this is for unit tests). So I'm bound to using a sequence.

Comment: Using a different DBMS for unit testing is wrong to begin with. This is just one example of many differences (sometimes obvious, sometimes very subtle) between the DBMS. A unit test that runs against a different DBMS isn't really a valid test.

Comment: But it does look like a bug to me. You might get a better response if you post this to the HSQLDB discussion group: http://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/discussion/73674/ (although Fred does read SO as well)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I understand your point, but HSQLDB and its "Oracle syntax" option has made a good job until now. It's really difficult to unit test against an oracle database (as not an embedded database), especially if tests are run on several different hosts (developer machine, jenkins etc.).

Comment: I created https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1377/

Answer (score 0):

Because triggers are set based, not row based.

See details [here](http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2008/06/05/triggers-set-based-not-row-based/)

Comment: That might be true for SQL Server, but not for HSQLDB. In HSQLDB (like in many other DBMS) you have the choice between row level triggers and statement level triggers. The trigger is explicitly created using `FOR EACH ROW` if you look at the example.

Comment: @Kenan In HSQLDB there is this `FOR EACH ROW`... so I don't think this is correct.