# Perform Update Trigger on SQLBulkCopy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have use SQLBulkCopy in my project. Now i have created Trigger on Table to update records in another Table but it is not working.

How can i accomplish task to insert records in one table using SQLBulkCopy and fire Trigger for each row inserted in table to update records of another Table. Please Help.

Comment: I think your question has already been answered here: [Fire trigger for every inserted row using SqlBulkCopy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002947/fire-trigger-for-every-inserted-row-using-sqlbulkcopy)

Comment: You can not, triggers are set based.

See more [here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298328/why-is-trigger-not-fired-on-every-single-row-when-using-insert-select-or-merg/27299055#27299055

Comment: @JoachimSauer - I haven't got my answer from that question. I want to fire trigger which update valve in another table while i am filling table using SQLBulkCopy.

Comment: what did you try so far? what you mean with 'it is not working'? do you have any error? please post some code